# Get full error stack trace

Tags: magento2, error, cli

I am converting a module from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2. I made the necessary changes (all the imports, extends, config files, changing the structure of the module, etc.), and now I'm trying to include it in my site.

The problem is that, when i run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get this error:
 `[ErrorException]
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`
. I know that is a generic error (because in the code I made didn't use the function call `array_merge()`).

My question is: How to get a full stack trace of the error when the previous command is run from a CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add -vvv to command, like: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv`